# How do I properly embed YouTube background play video?

Tags: java, html, youtube, embedding

I am attempting to implement background music on my website hosted for free. It is a static HTML site, I watched some tutorials on this but it doesn't seem to do its job.

I am on Chrome.

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" src="https://listenonrepeat.com/watch/?v=b8I-iVBDugo#Verse_One_-_Skyline_-_Instrumental_Song_for_Anime_Opening_and_Background_Music_(No_Copyright)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> '+
```

I put this in the right place on my website but it does not autoplay like tutorials show.

Am I doing something wrong? I've been trying a lot of different things. (hence why I even attempted to use a repeat/loop site to embed it)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:java]?

Comment: Oh, on accident I think. Sorry if it brings any confusion. I used Java for some things.